# using php session variables created in a Ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, session, drupal, drupal-7

Hi I have link which calls a JavaScript function on clicking it which have an Ajax call to a php file. in php I have created a session and stored some values. After coming out of that Ajax call that i am unable to access that session variables...
Is there anything I have to do while working with Ajax???
This is my PHP in Ajax call

```
 <?php
session_start();
    $_SESSION[$_REQUEST["p"]][$_REQUEST["p_id"]]=$_REQUEST["p_id"];
    print_r($_SESSION[$_REQUEST["p"]]);
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help....

Comment: Can you show us the ajax call ?

Comment: A handy way to debug ajax is by opening the "Network tab" in the chrome developper tools (or a similar tab for other browsers). In chrome: F12, then click on `network tab`. It will show you if your ajax file is executed, and if there is any error.

Comment: @pinouchon sorry 4 late reply actually i have found the main problem just now. the session created in ajax call and session created outside are different so wat can i do now???? any ideas???

Comment: @pinouchon I have checked it with network tab and found no error was there

Comment: Yes, but do you see and entry such as "myajaxfile.php", with the print_r contents when you click on it ? If so, then you have to retrieve that and display it properly via javascript, where the call returns. If not, then your ajax file is not called.

Comment: no my ajax call is working it showed in network tab and also i can get the output from it

Answer (score 0):

In drupal no need to give session start separately.

1. try to remove session_start and print_r $_SESSION variable
2. If you are getting the result no issue with session, otherwise for maintaining anonymous user session check in user table uid 0 is there or not.